# Какая разница между формами инкремента i++ и ++i в цикле for?

Tags: javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    alert(i); // 0,1,2,3,4
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    alert(i); // 0,1,2,3,4
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z0ugbbwj/

Не увидел разницы.

Comment: в данном примере никакой, ходят _легенды_ что ++i быстрее (частично верно для сложных объектов). Ну и если выражение побольше чем i++ то приоритет может изменять смысл.

Comment: @pavel ну по идее это не легенды, ведь с постфиксным инкрементом там же идёт запоминание предыдущего значения. странно что везде и всех приучили писать именно его.

Comment: хороший компилятор это сам преобразует.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В приведённом примере разницы нет. Подробнее про легенды, что `++i` быстрее.

Ходят слухи, что для выполнения `++i` значение в памяти увеличивается и затем возвращается. В то время, как для `i++` сначала запоминается значение в создаваемой временной переменной, потом увеличивается значение основной и возвращается значение временной – таким образом увеличиваются «расходы» на создание временной переменной.

[Перформанс тест](https://jsperf.com/preincrement-vs-postincrement-vs-predecrement-vs-postde/5) не удаётся посмотреть из-за временного косяка на их стороне.

Comment: Шел второй год временного косяка..

Answer (score 7):

В данном случае разницы нет, так как это выражение выполняется в конце итерации и может быть переписано таким образом

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5;) {
  console.log(i); // 0,1,2,3,4
  ++i;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5;) {
  console.log(i); // 0,1,2,3,4
  i++;
}
```

Так как это выражение выполняется отдельно, и его возвращаемое значение не используется - нет никакой разницы как именно менять значение переменной, абсолютно аналогичные варианты:

```
i += 1;
i = i+1;
i = inc(i);
...
```

Разница появится при использовании инкремента во втором блоке:

```js
for (var i = 0; ++i < 5;) {
  console.log(i); // 1,2,3,4
}

for (var i = 0; i++ < 5;) {
  console.log(i); // 1,2,3,4,5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Разница в том, что `++i` инкрементирует, а затем возвращает значение. `i++` возвращает значение, а потом инкрементирует.