# Что лучше использовать и что скорее $i++ или ++$i или $i+=1

Tags: php, javascript

Что лучше использовать и что скорее работает?

`$i++`, `++$i` или `$i+=1` ?

Comment: так javascript или php?

Comment: или `$i = $i + 1`? =)

Comment: хотелось бы узнать в обоих

Comment: и что такое "что скорее" ? Если вы про скорость работы то все одинаково. А префиксную и постфиксную запись - откройте первый попавшийся учебник по языку и увидите, что приоритет операций т.е. порядок их выполнения зависит от записи

Comment: тоесть ви хотите сказать что ++$i и $i++ равни в скорости роботи?

Comment: Однозначно мы можем утверждать только то, что `inc eax` работает быстрее, чем `add eax, 1`. Хотя нет, не можем.

Comment: мы хотим сказать, что если разница в скорости этих двух операторов критична, то писать надо на ассемблере

Comment: закрыл как дубликат с указанием PHP, т.к. пример кода явно на PHP. Вот точно такой же вопрос по JavaScript: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540829

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, выбирать между ними надо на основе необходимого возвращаемого значения.

Во-вторых, если возвращаемое значение нами не используется, хорошие компиляторы должны бы догадаться, что это всё одно и то же и сделать одинаковый код.

Дальше. В оригинальном виде инструкции выглядят как-то так:

```
; ++i
inc eax

; i++
mov ebx, eax
inc eax

; i += 1
add eax, 1
```

Очевидно, что первый вариант не может быть медленнее остальных. Однако, во-втором компилятор должен бы понять, что мы не используем скопированное значение и выкинуть лишнюю инструкцию, а в третьем во-первых, не ясно, действительно ли сложение менее оптимально, а во-вторых, компилятор тоже может это понять.

Вывод: если нет разницы, писать `++i`, а компилятор разберётся.

Кстати, использование подобных вариантов ассемблерного кода уже предполагает, что были применены некоторые оптимизации. Потому что по идеологии большинства языков (видимо, кроме Си и Си++) инструкция инкремента распадается на несколько: чтение, сложение и присваивание.

В javascript'е мы даже можем сделать, чтобы чтение и запись происходила с разными объектами:

```js
var p = { x: 7 }
var o = Object.create(p);
++o.x;
console.log(p.x); // по-прежнему 7
console.log(o.x); // а вот тут уже своя 8
```

Comment: Делегировать компилятору угадайку можно, в данном случае может даже нужно, но компилятор не может облагородить весь код, нужно всё равно знать как и что работает :)

Comment: @Other, я ещё один момент в ответ добавил.

Comment: Да, забавный факт. Только почему игнорируется факт того, что читают и пишут в разные места? Вроде прочли прототип и туда же пишем. Ошибка, конечно, не выход, свойство-то есть.

Comment: @Other, потому что пишем всегда в объект. Нет случаев, когда это не так.

Comment: Это я знаю. Вот только прототип - тоже объект. И всегда объект.

Comment: @Other, только в _текущий_ объект, я имел в виду. Никаких записей в прототип. Никогда.

Comment: Т. е. обращаясь к объекту, невозможно записать что-то в его прототип, так? Где-то я об этом слышал.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53326/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-other).

Comment: @Qwertiy ни один вменяемый компилятор не сделает из `i += 1` инструкцию `add eax, 1`

Comment: @PashaPash, я вроде об этом сказал. Но синтаксически это именно add 1.

Comment: @Qwertiy синтаксически это `i += 1`, как это реализуется внутри - полносью на совести компилятора. Например, компилятор из C# в IL превратит `i++` в `ldc.i4.1, add` - т.е. фактически в `i += 1` - поломав все предположения о синтаксичности :)

Comment: @PashaPash, про это тоже есть в ответе - после вывода :) Кстати, а jit-компилятор как с этим поступит?

Comment: @Qwertiy ответе есть кусок ". В оригинальном виде инструкции выглядят как-то так", который прямо вот так собой говорит `i += 1` это `add eax, 1`, а `; ++i` - это `inc eax`. и тут же написан вывод "Очевидно, что первый вариант не может быть медленнее остальных" - который прямо подразумевает что вот по дефлоту, "без оптимизаций" именно так все и выполняется. Хотя в том же C#/IL это не так. Ну и окончательный вывод "если нет разницы, писать ++i, а компилятор разберётся" - почему нужно писать именно ++i? почему не i++?

Comment: @Qwertiy jit (и даже стандартный .net / release в il) может вообще выбросить *весь инкремент*, если результат не используется.

Answer (score 0):

```
function test(nominal){
    var i = nominal;
    console.time();
    while(i){
        i--;
    }
    console.timeEnd();
    i = nominal;
    console.time();
    while(i){
        --i;
    }
    console.timeEnd();
    i = nominal;
    console.time();
    while(i){
        i = i - 1;
    }
    console.timeEnd();
}
```

Получили:

```
test(10000000)
VM146:7 default: 50.000ms
VM146:13 default: 31.000ms
VM146:19 default: 25.000ms
undefined
test(10000000)
VM146:7 default: 34.000ms
VM146:13 default: 34.000ms
VM146:19 default: 25.000ms
undefined
test(10000000)
VM146:7 default: 49.000ms
VM146:13 default: 32.000ms
VM146:19 default: 24.000ms
undefined
test(10000000)
VM146:7 default: 50.000ms
VM146:13 default: 32.000ms
VM146:19 default: 24.000ms
undefined
test(10000000)
VM146:7 default: 34.000ms
VM146:13 default: 33.000ms
VM146:19 default: 24.000ms
undefined
test(10000000)
VM146:7 default: 42.000ms
VM146:13 default: 26.000ms
VM146:19 default: 24.000ms
```

---

Раскрываем тему `php`

```
$nom = 10000000;
function test($nominal){
    $time = -microtime(true);
    $i = $nominal;
    while($i){
        $i--;
    }
    $time += microtime(true);
    echo $time.' secs(i--), ';

    $time = -microtime(true);
    $i = $nominal;
    while($i){
        --$i;
    }
    $time += microtime(true);
    echo $time.' secs(--i), ';

    $time = -microtime(true);
    $i = $nominal;
    while($i){
        $i = $i - 1;
    }
    $time += microtime(true);
    echo $time.' secs(i-1), ';
}

$k = 10;
while($k--){
    echo '<br/>';
    test($nom);
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

>>>

```
1.3539199829102 secs(i--), 1.2611348628998 secs(--i), 1.3199110031128 secs(i-1), 

1.1811420917511 secs(i--), 1.3495378494263 secs(--i), 1.3187339305878 secs(i-1), 

1.1476590633392 secs(i--), 1.2748289108276 secs(--i), 1.3125870227814 secs(i-1), 

1.1294658184052 secs(i--), 1.2662220001221 secs(--i), 1.3234519958496 secs(i-1), 

1.1132800579071 secs(i--), 1.2643389701843 secs(--i), 1.3241758346558 secs(i-1), 

1.1115510463715 secs(i--), 1.3130419254303 secs(--i), 1.3356699943542 secs(i-1), 

1.1359589099884 secs(i--), 1.3663308620453 secs(--i), 1.3912291526794 secs(i-1), 

1.2231979370117 secs(i--), 1.3729820251465 secs(--i), 1.4119091033936 secs(i-1), 

1.3028910160065 secs(i--), 1.3418638706207 secs(--i), 1.3546941280365 secs(i-1), 

1.1213128566742 secs(i--), 1.2591190338135 secs(--i), 1.347608089447 secs(i-1),
```

Comment: тема PHP не раскрыта

Comment: @PashaPash, думаете в пэхапэ будут другие результаты при таких тестах?

Comment: @PashaPash, раскрыл

Comment: @Other, на удивление, не могу сказать, что они явно похожи.

Comment: Мой хром с тобой не согласен. Последнее - самое медленное: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1VYw.png (естественно, первый запуск не считается - там функция компилировалась).

Comment: За тести конешно спасибо

Comment: @Qwertiy Мой хром теперь не согласен даже с собой 40 минут назад.

Comment: [мой тест](http://joxi.ru/L214pgyHMXj8mX) ну ето в каво как

Comment: И php не сходится: http://ideone.com/C9zQ1y 14 11 16 - второе самое быстрое.

Comment: @vov4ok, только результаты тестов у всех разные...

Answer (score -1):

Посмотрите тут: 
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.increment.php

```
<?php

$i = 1;
$j = 1;

echo '$i = '. ++$i;

echo '$j = '. $j++;
----
$i = 2;
$j = 1;
```

Вот основная разница.

Comment: был вопрос не в чем разница видимая, а в производительности

Comment: человек так же спросил "что лучше использовать".

Comment: и где ответ на вопрос `что лучше использовать` ? вижу только вот **разница**

Comment: Про разницу я в курсе

Comment: даже как-то стыдно уже, что я тут ответил.